# How to deploy WPF Applications to client machines without a server?

Tags: sql-server, wpf, web

I've created a wpf application. Now I need to make an application to download it from a web site to various client machines with no server software. What are the essential requirements that need to be installed from the web to the client in order for the application to work? I am very new to this and am learning as i go along

Comment: What kind of project is it? What kind of references does it use? Is Click-once a solution or not?

Comment: Have you considered ClickOnce?

Comment: [ClickOnce Deployment Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/142dbbz4(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the others you may publish your application using clickonce. An alternative approuch is to use a third party installer like wise(yee old .msi is removed from newer visual studios). MS wants you to use clickonce for deployment it may be done manually using mage, through MageUI or visual studio directly. I only use mage.exe for deployment of WPF and XBAP applications, it's nice if you have a buildserver set up and all. Just make some scripts for the deployment that you may reuse, once deployed check your manifest file to see what's included and not.

[General information about clickonce.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(v=vs.80).ASPX)

[Mage.exe located in your windows sdk for manually deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te(v=vs.110).aspx)

[MageUI, useless for any live production envirnoment...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhctdw55(v=vs.110).aspx)

Hope it helps you some, I know this can be a pain.

Cheers,

Stian

Comment: thanks for your comments. If I may expand a little. The application is a standalone sqlserver database application which has been built on my home pc. I want to upload the application and all required software to a website and then allow the public, through a web application to download the software to their machine to run solely on their machine.